Proving the volume formular

With $a > 0$ and $n \geq 2$, denote $$ S_n(a) = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) :
 |x_i| + |x_n| \leq a \text{ and } 0 \leq x_i \leq a \text{ for each }
 i = 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}. $$ Assume $V_n(a)$ is the $n$-dimensional
measure of $S_n(a)$. Prove that  $$ V_n(a) = \frac{2^n  a^n}{n}. $$

We have the following formular: $$V_n(a)=\int_{S_n(a)} 1 dx$$with $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$
By setting $x=at$ with $t=(t_1,...,t_n)$, I obtain $$V_n(a)=a^nV_n(1)$$
I don't know how to continue. Could someone help me? Thank very much!

anyone..........?

The word is "formula", not "formular".

The problem is a bit weird. I believe you forgot an absolute value notation. $S_n$ should be
$$S_n(a)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):|x_i|+|x_n|\le a\text{ and }0\le|x_i|\le a\text{ for each }i=1,2,\dots,n-1\}$$
if the answer is $V_n(a)=\frac{2^na^n}n$. But then the second condition is implied in the first condition.
It suffices to prove $V_n(1)=\frac{2^n}n$. The condition for each variable $x_k$ $(k=1,\cdots,n-1)$ in $S_n$ is$$|x_k|+|x_n|\le1.$$In other words, $-1+|x_n|\le x_k\le1-|x_n|$. Then the integral you are looking for is$$V_n(1)=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1+|x_n|}^{1-|x_n|}\cdots\int_{-1+|x_n|}^{1-|x_n|}dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}dx_n.$$Since the integral is symmetric in all variables,$$V_n(1)=2^n\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x_n}\cdots\int_0^{1-x_n}dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}dx_n.$$
We have$$V_n(1)=2^n\int_0^1(1-x_n)^{n-1}dx_n=\frac{2^n}n.$$

Even easier, get the first orthant (where each coordinate is non-negative) as $\int_0^a(a-x_n)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x_n$ then multiply by $2^n$.
